# Equivalence of a statement and its complement (Logic)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic

Say that two natural numbers $i,j$ are *separated* if $\lvert i-j\rvert>M$, where $M>0$ is a constant. In the paper I'm reading, the author defined $\Gamma$ as "the set of tuples $(i,i',j,j')\in [n]^4$ such that **none of the indices $i,i',j,j'$ is separated from the others** and $\Gamma^c$ is its complement". Here, $[n]:=\{1,\dotsc,n\}$, and $[n]^4=[n]\times [n]\times[n] \times [n]$.

As far as I understand, I can write  $\Gamma=\{A\in[n]^4:\nexists k\in A: \forall l \in A\setminus\{k\}: \lvert k-l\rvert>M \}$.

This definition is not clear to me. Is $\Gamma$ equivalent to :

1. "the set of tuples $(i,i',j,j')\in [n]^4$ such that **each $i,i',j,j'$ is not separated from the others** ", that is, $\Gamma=\{A\in[n]^4:\forall k\in A: \forall l \in A\setminus\{k\}: \lvert k-l\rvert\leq M \}$; or
2. "the set of tuples $(i,i',j,j')\in [n]^4$ such that **each $i,i',j,j'$ is not separated from some other index** ", that is, $\Gamma=\{A\in[n]^4:\forall k\in A: \exists l \in A\setminus\{k\}: \lvert k-l\rvert\leq M \}$.

Can you help me? Additionaly, what   would be $\Gamma^c$?

If 1 is true, then
$$\Gamma^c=\{A\in[n]^4:\exists k\in A: \exists l \in A\setminus\{k\}: \lvert k-l\rvert> M \}.$$
If 2 is true, then 
$$\Gamma^c=\{A\in[n]^4:\exists k\in A: \forall l \in A\setminus\{k\}: \lvert k-l\rvert> M \}.$$

I appreciate any help to clarify this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is 1. And you can even simplify your expression with a little trick. Since $|k - k| \leqslant M$ is always true for $M \geqslant 0$, you get :

$$ \Gamma=\{A\in[n]^4:\forall k\in A, \forall l \in A, \lvert k-l\rvert\leq M \}$$

Hence,

$$ \Gamma^c=\{A\in[n]^4:\exists k\in A, \exists l \in A, \lvert k-l\rvert> M \}$$